# Is there any way to embed a Xilium.CefGlue/Chromium browser using Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, chromium-embedded

I am working on a project on Visual Studio 2008, using .Net Framework 3.5, and I have to embed a Xilium.CefGlue browser (or possibly Chromium, but not WebKit nor IE), but the only Xilium.CefGlue download I have found was a source code created with Visual Studio 2012 which does not compile in 2008 (mainly because 2008 is missing a large number of DLLs, like System.xaml, GTK, etc.). Is there an older version which is compatible with Visual Studio 2008, or a DLL which I can include in my project?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to do it, using the source code.

First, open one of the projects (not the solution) with Visual Studio.

Then, change each of the project's settings to use .Net framework 3.5, and build them one by one, EXCEPT for the GTK one (which I didn't need anyway).

Finally, grab the generated DLLs and use them in your project.